# Linq: Grouping elements with a condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list-

```
    public class SecretAgents
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public List<string> SecretData {get; set;}
        public int GroupID {get; set;}
    }

    List<SecretAgents> secretAgents = new List<SecretAgents>();

    // Each item has a total of 256 elements in it under the
    // SecretData list of string that consists of "apple" and "orange"

    secretAgents.Add(new SecretAgents { Name= "SecretAgent 1", GroupID= 0, SecretData= new List<string> { "orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple" } });
    secretAgents.Add(new SecretAgents { Name= "SecretAgent 2", GroupID= 0, SecretData= new List<string> { "apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange" } });
    secretAgents.Add(new SecretAgents { Name= "SecretAgent 3", GroupID= 0, SecretData= new List<string> { "orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","apple","apple" } });
    secretAgents.Add(new SecretAgents { Name= "SecretAgent 4", GroupID= 0, SecretData= new List<string> { "orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","apple","apple","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange" } });
```

Equal elements ("apple" and "orange") between different items:

- Secret Agent 1 & Secret Agent 3: 248
- Secret Agent 2 & Secret Agent 4: 256

In rest other possibilities (for example: Agent 1 & Agent 3, Agent 2 & Agent 3, etc.), equal elements are lesser than 200.

Now, what I want is to group all items (Secret Agents) that have a minimum of 200 equal elements ("apple" and "orange").

**Expected Results**

Secret Agent 1: Group ID 1

Secret Agent 3: Group ID 1

Secret Agent 2: Group ID 2

Secret Agent 4: Group ID 2

**Pseudo Code:**

Iterate through each item in the `secretAgents` list and then use `Linq Zip` function:

```
    int index=0;    
    foreach(var item in secretAgents)
    {
        index++;
        int equalElements = item.Zip(item, (i, j) => i.SecretData == j.SecretData).Count(eq => eq);
        if (equalElements>200)
        {
            item.GroupID=index;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "Equal elements ("apple" and "orange") between different items" and "In rest other possibilities" mean?

Comment: Equal elements that we  find when we use `int equalElements = list.Zip(list, (i, j) => i == j).Count(eq => eq);`

Comment: how are you determining the groupID? what does 1 and 2 mean?

Comment: We've to compare each Secret Agent with another Secret Agent in the list. When multiple Secret Agents have equal elements that are larger than 200, they are considered to be in the same group. For example: Agent 1 and Agent 3 have 248 equal elements, thus they're in Group 1, Similarly, Agent 2 and 4 are in Group 2 as they have 256 equal elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a painful query:

```
var query =
    from q in
    (
        from sa1 in secretAgents
        from sa2 in secretAgents
        where sa1.Name.CompareTo(sa2.Name) == -1
        let count = sa1.SecretData.Zip(sa2.SecretData, (First, Second) => (First, Second)).Where(x => x.First == x.Second).Count()
        where count > 200
        group new[] { sa1, sa2 } by count
    ).Select((xss, i) => (xss, i))
    from xs in q.xss
    from x in xs
    select new { Name = x.Name, GroupID = q.i + 1 };
```

It gives me:

[image: query]

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error "No overload for method 'Zip' takes 1 arguments" on this line: `sa.SecretData.Zip`

Comment: @KittyCat - That's a .NET 6.0 overload. I'll update the answer with the method that works for the earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be grateful for that.

2) Also, if I may ask, will it be possible to show % Similarity of equal elements by adding a new column `public int Similarity {get; set;}`

Comment: @KittyCat - Can you define "Similarity" for these two lists? `{ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", }` & `{ "a", "q", "c", "f", }`.

Comment: Since both lists will have equal number of elements, I remove "e" from the list 1 above. Thus, first list will be 50% similar of 2nd list.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I checked your edited code, but still getting different errors. Here's my DotNetFiddle code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=vClGQtoVvJ

Comment: 2 instances of `Syntax error, '=>' expected` error and another 2 instances of `) expected` error appearing on below lines (1) `"let count..."`  (2) `).Select((xss`

Comment: @KittyCat - I test my code before posting. It works as it is.

Comment: @KittyCat - The code in your fiddle has nothing to do with this question/answer. Have you linked to the correct one?

Comment: Someone did mischief by overwriting my code with theirs as my link was public :) I'm getting those errors on .NET 4.7.2 but not on .Net 6. Can anything be done? Thanks.

Comment: @KittyCat - Yes, copy my code exactly.

Comment: I did sir exactly. I'm still getting the above error only on .NET 4.7.2 but as soon as I switch to .NET 6, I don't. Unfortunately, I can't upgrade my project to .NET 6 due to some other compatibility issues. Anyways, I'm accepting your answer. I really value your time and help. Thanks.

Comment: I tried upgrading my project to .NET 6 but many components don't work :(

Comment: Can you please post your code as you should get any errors on 4.7.2?

Comment: @KittyCat - Sorry, I just noticed your answer to my comment 4th from the top. The lists have different numbers of elements.

Comment: No issues Sir. I deeply respect your help, valuable time contribution. Thanks!

Comment: @KittyCat - Can you define "Similarity" for these two lists? `{ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", }` & `{ "a", "q", "c", "f", }`.

Comment: I managed to get that done Sir using some alternate technique I tried. Since both lists will have equal number of elements in my case, I remove "e" from first list. Then first list has 50% similar items compared to second list.